# Show images at pixel accuracy in WPF applications

Tags: c#, wpf, image

I want to show some images in a WPF application, however Microsoft "smartly" scales everything to the incorrect scale! What I want, is to show the images at pixel accuracy. I.e. if the image is 50x50, I want to show it exactly 50 pixels and 50 pixels on the screen, no matter what is the DPI setting of the image / screen.

I have tried the following, which does not work:

1. Set the .png image dpi to 96.
2. Add the line `[assembly: System.Windows.Media.DisableDpiAwareness]` in AssemblyInfo.cs

The problem is, I sit far from my screen, so in Control Panel I set the text size to be larger. But I can tell the image is not correctly sized, because it is larger and blurred when I open the same image in Photoshop side by side.

Comment: See this [blogpost](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx)

Comment: solution: use vector graphics.

Answer (score 0):

Dwayne Need created an excellent blog post about this issue, which can be found [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/dwayneneed/archive/2007/10/05/blurry-bitmaps.aspx). The code is also available at the same location. To quote him:

> The code included below introduces a new class called Bitmap.  Bitmap is a replacement for Image, but instead of displaying any image source, it only displays bitmap sources.  This lets me access the PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties for determining the appropriate size.  The important aspects of this class are:
>
> - Derived from UIElement instead of FrameworkElement because I don’t want things like MinWidth, MaxWidth, or even Width.
> - Bitmap.Source can be set to any BitmapSource.
> - When measured, it will return the appropriate measure units to display the bitmap’s PixelWidth and PixelHeight
> - When rendered, it will offset the image it draws to align with the pixel grid
> - Whenever layout updates, it checks to see if it needs to re-render to align to the pixel grid again.
>
> Its a pretty straight-forward class, check out the source code for the details.

I hope he doesn't mind if I share the code also here:

Example Window (a much better example can be found in the original code...):

```
<Window x:Class="ImageSnappingToPixels.Window1"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ImageSnappingToPixels"
    Height="300" Width="600">
  <Grid x:Name="root">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
      <local:Bitmap Source="picture1.png" />
      <local:Bitmap Source="picture2.png" />
    </StackPanel>
  </Grid>
</Window>
```

And here is his complete and unabridged Bitmap class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace ImageSnappingToPixels
{
    class Bitmap : UIElement
    {
        public Bitmap()
        {
            _sourceDownloaded = new EventHandler(OnSourceDownloaded);
            _sourceFailed = new EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs>(OnSourceFailed);

            LayoutUpdated += new EventHandler(OnLayoutUpdated);
        }

        public static readonly DependencyProperty SourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
            "Source",
            typeof(BitmapSource),
            typeof(Bitmap),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
                null,
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsRender |
                FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.AffectsMeasure,
                new PropertyChangedCallback(Bitmap.OnSourceChanged)));

        public BitmapSource Source
        {
            get
            {
                return (BitmapSource) GetValue(SourceProperty);
            }
            set
            {
                SetValue(SourceProperty, value);
            }
        }

        public event EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs> BitmapFailed;

        // Return our measure size to be the size needed to display the bitmap pixels.
        protected override Size MeasureCore(Size availableSize)
        {
            Size measureSize = new Size();

            BitmapSource bitmapSource = Source;
            if(bitmapSource != null)
            {
                PresentationSource ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
                if (ps != null)
                {
                    Matrix fromDevice = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice;

                    Vector pixelSize = new Vector(bitmapSource.PixelWidth, bitmapSource.PixelHeight);
                    Vector measureSizeV = fromDevice.Transform(pixelSize);
                    measureSize = new Size(measureSizeV.X, measureSizeV.Y);
                }
            }

            return measureSize;
        }

        protected override void OnRender(DrawingContext dc)
        {
            BitmapSource bitmapSource = this.Source;
            if (bitmapSource != null)
            {
                _pixelOffset = GetPixelOffset();

                // Render the bitmap offset by the needed amount to align to pixels.
                dc.DrawImage(bitmapSource, new Rect(_pixelOffset, DesiredSize));
            }
        }

        private static void OnSourceChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap)d;

            BitmapSource oldValue = (BitmapSource)e.OldValue;
            BitmapSource newValue = (BitmapSource)e.NewValue;

            if (((oldValue != null) && (bitmap._sourceDownloaded != null)) && (!oldValue.IsFrozen && (oldValue is BitmapSource)))
            {
                ((BitmapSource)oldValue).DownloadCompleted -= bitmap._sourceDownloaded;
                ((BitmapSource)oldValue).DownloadFailed -= bitmap._sourceFailed;
                // ((BitmapSource)newValue).DecodeFailed -= bitmap._sourceFailed; // 3.5
            }
            if (((newValue != null) && (newValue is BitmapSource)) && !newValue.IsFrozen)
            {
                ((BitmapSource)newValue).DownloadCompleted += bitmap._sourceDownloaded;
                ((BitmapSource)newValue).DownloadFailed += bitmap._sourceFailed;
                // ((BitmapSource)newValue).DecodeFailed += bitmap._sourceFailed; // 3.5
            }
        }

        private void OnSourceDownloaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            InvalidateMeasure();
            InvalidateVisual();
        }

        private void OnSourceFailed(object sender, ExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Source = null; // setting a local value seems scetchy...

            BitmapFailed(this, e);
        }

        private void OnLayoutUpdated(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // This event just means that layout happened somewhere.  However, this is
            // what we need since layout anywhere could affect our pixel positioning.
            Point pixelOffset = GetPixelOffset();
            if (!AreClose(pixelOffset, _pixelOffset))
            {
                InvalidateVisual();
            }
        }

        // Gets the matrix that will convert a point from "above" the
        // coordinate space of a visual into the the coordinate space
        // "below" the visual.
        private Matrix GetVisualTransform(Visual v)
        {
            if (v != null)
            {
                Matrix m = Matrix.Identity;

                Transform transform = VisualTreeHelper.GetTransform(v);
                if (transform != null)
                {
                    Matrix cm = transform.Value;
                    m = Matrix.Multiply(m, cm);
                }

                Vector offset = VisualTreeHelper.GetOffset(v);
                m.Translate(offset.X, offset.Y);

                return m;
            }

            return Matrix.Identity;
        }

        private Point TryApplyVisualTransform(Point point, Visual v, bool inverse, bool throwOnError, out bool success)
        {
            success = true;
            if (v != null)
            {
                Matrix visualTransform = GetVisualTransform(v);
                if (inverse)
                {
                    if (!throwOnError && !visualTransform.HasInverse)
                    {
                        success = false;
                        return new Point(0, 0);
                    }
                    visualTransform.Invert();
                }
                point = visualTransform.Transform(point);
            }
            return point;
        }

        private Point ApplyVisualTransform(Point point, Visual v, bool inverse)
        {
            bool success = true;
            return TryApplyVisualTransform(point, v, inverse, true, out success);
        }

        private Point GetPixelOffset()
        {
            Point pixelOffset = new Point();

            PresentationSource ps = PresentationSource.FromVisual(this);
            if (ps != null)
            {
                Visual rootVisual = ps.RootVisual;

                // Transform (0,0) from this element up to pixels.
                pixelOffset = this.TransformToAncestor(rootVisual).Transform(pixelOffset);
                pixelOffset = ApplyVisualTransform(pixelOffset, rootVisual, false);
                pixelOffset = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformToDevice.Transform(pixelOffset);

                // Round the origin to the nearest whole pixel.
                pixelOffset.X = Math.Round(pixelOffset.X);
                pixelOffset.Y = Math.Round(pixelOffset.Y);

                // Transform the whole-pixel back to this element.
                pixelOffset = ps.CompositionTarget.TransformFromDevice.Transform(pixelOffset);
                pixelOffset = ApplyVisualTransform(pixelOffset, rootVisual, true);
                pixelOffset = rootVisual.TransformToDescendant(this).Transform(pixelOffset);
            }

            return pixelOffset;
        }

        private bool AreClose(Point point1, Point point2)
        {
            return AreClose(point1.X, point2.X) && AreClose(point1.Y, point2.Y);
        }

        private bool AreClose(double value1, double value2)
        {
            if (value1 == value2)
            {
                return true;
            }
            double delta = value1 - value2;
            return ((delta < 1.53E-06) && (delta > -1.53E-06));
        }

        private EventHandler _sourceDownloaded;
        private EventHandler<ExceptionEventArgs> _sourceFailed;
        private Point _pixelOffset;
    }
}
```